# is there a junit extension to record memory taken per test

Tags: java, memory-leaks, junit

We use JUnit  it for normal unit testing, integration testing, feature testing etc.

It will be useful to record memory consumed by individual test and compare with different run. Is there any JUnit extension that does this sort of thing already? (apparently IntelliJ 's JUnit runner does this)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should use one of those open source memory profilers along with your JUnit suite.
[Here](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers) is the list.

Comment: That is good starting point. What I am looking at is to introduce the recording part.  Looks like junit has listeners/hooks to do this.